# Visual Studio 2015 update 2 snippets issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I had found a strange behavior in the last update of visual studio 2015 community edition.
When I insert a snippet and change the name of a variable, this change does not made for all variable with same name of the snippet, e.g. I use a Mvvmlight framework and I use the mvvmlight snippet like lightprop:

```
 private string _MyProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _MyProperty; }
        set
        {
            _MyProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged<string>(() => this.MyProperty);
        }
    }
```

Well, I change the name of _MyProperty to _name for example, but the variable in the get not does changed, i will change it manually.

What is the problem??? In the Visual studio 2015 i had not this issue.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Double click the name, right-click, select refactor-> rename

Comment: Great, It Works!!! Thank you @TimSchmelter, but in the previous version of Visual Studio there was no need do that, it did automatically  .